# Mixed model ANOVA and linear regression in python with two dimensional spline function

Tags: python, anova, spline, mixed

I used to work with R, but am trying to solve the same problem in Python now. To analyse plant breeding trials I have used the "sommer" package in R for mixed modelling with two dimensional splines. Now I want to recreate the same in python. I realise that there is the pingouin and statsmodels package for mixed model ANOVA, but is there a way or another package that can incorporate a two dimensional spline as a random effect for handling field inhomogeneity. The trials I am trying to analyse are non-replicated but using check plots.

Best Regards